# How to make the Escape key close the chat window in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

In Pidgin we can select "Close conversations with the Escape key" in the preferences to close the chat window. Is there anything similar in Empathy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the functionality you're looking for is the same as 'Close Window' you can try to use

```
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels true
```

then hover your mouse over the 'Close window' menu option in empathy and then hit ESC. ESC should now be written next to close window.
Be sure to turn off the gconf setting afterwards

```
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels false
```

There used to be a option in the menu for this but I think it's turned off in 10.04 (Sorry, can't check just now)

Comment: yes your are right, i think have seen this option in the previous versions of empathy

Comment: i am using Empathy 2.32.0.1. Where is this "Close window" option.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but this is one of the top searches in Google for this, so I thought I should post the answer here.
The source is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/486508/comments/11

> I just had that issue, you can modify /usr/share/empathy/empathy-chat-window.ui and change the line that says:
>   `<accelerator key="W" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>`
>
> to
>
> `<accelerator key="Escape" />`
>
> and ask for forgiveness to the gods that decided that would be a sin, cheers

Comment: Thanks - found this through Google and it was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not a feature of empathy. Though empathy is default (and replaces pidgin), please remember that empathy is a much younger project and some things may have not made it in as yet, or may have been unintentionally overlooked.

You could report a bug to the empathy developers.